# Define simple java class, then error while writing(Permission denied)

Tags: java, windows

I just begin to learn Java, and write a simple java code to define class

```
import java.util.*;
class People {
    People() {
        System.out.println("New people");
    }   
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            new People();
        }   
    }   
}
```

Then I use javac to compile it, and some error happened

```
Test.java:3: error: error while writing People: People.class (Permission denied)
class People {
^
1 error
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error while writing People: People.class (Permission denied)

It has no relation with java code.
You execute the `javac` command with a user that has not the rights to create a file (the generated .class) where you try to do it.
Just check the rights of the user and the folder where you generate the `.class` files and adjust the one or the other.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I create the directory in root but execute `javac` in normal user.It can be solved by `chown` command. Thanks!

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson the downvoter specialist. I knew it. Advise if I may : you should edit your profile and add this skill.

Comment: @Edure you are welcome :)